# How to write Contact Card to NFC tags

Tags: android, nfc, contacts

I am trying to write an app which writes NFC tag with contact details. Can you please tell me what should be the "type" for NdefRecord for contact card.

```
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, "RTD_URI".getBytes(),
            new byte[] {}, messagebytes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the vCard format for the contact details, you can use

```
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, 
  "text/vcard".getBytes(), new byte[] {}, messagebytes);
```

where `messagebytes` is the actual vCard data.